# UIAxes' YLim property cannot be listened to

Tags: matlab, observable, listener, matlab-figure, matlab-app-designer

MATLAB provides the [`addlistener`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle.addlistener.html) function.

Listeners allow us to keep track of changes of an object's properties and act upon them. For example, we can create a very simple listener that will display a message in the command window when the `'YLim'` property of an [`axes`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes.html) object is changed:

```
% Example using axes
ax = axes();
addlistener(ax, 'YLim', 'PostSet', @(src, evnt)disp('YLim changed'));
```

Try panning the axes or zooming in/out and see what happens. This works fine.

I need to do the same but using an [`uiaxes`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uiaxes.html) instead.

Unfortunately, it looks like we are not allowed to do so. Try running the following example:

```
% Example using uiaxes
ax = uiaxes();
addlistener(ax, 'YLim', 'PostSet', @(src, evnt)disp('YLim changed'));
```

It throws this error:

> Error using matlab.ui.control.UIAxes/addlistener While adding a
>   PostSet listener, property 'YLim' in class 'matlab.ui.control.UIAxes'
>   is not defined to be SetObservable.

I've read the articles [Listen for Changes to Property Values](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/listening-for-changes-to-property-values.html) and [Observe Changes to Property Values](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/class-to-observe-property-changes.html) and I learned that a property must be declared as `SetObservable` to allow being listened:

```
classdef PropLis < handle
   properties (SetObservable)
      ObservedProp = 1 % <-- Observable Property
   end
end
```

I've tried taking a look at the `UIAxes` class definition via `edit matlab.ui.control.UIAxes` but it's not possible because it's a [P-file](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcode.html).

If `'YLim'` is not observable then how can I keep track of changes in this property?

I'm using [App Designer](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/app-designer.html) in MATLAB R2018b.

Comment: Wow. Tough question. The _Observability_ of traditional `axes` is already a bit of touch and go (read [Loren's post](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2015/12/14/axes-limits-scream-louder-i-cant-hear-you/) for more details), although I successfully managed to attach working listeners to those. The technique didn't work for the new `uiaxes` but this post on Matlab Central may offer you a clunky workaround for now: https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/433573-app-designer-how-to-link-axes-of-uiaxes-components-to-enable-user-to-zoom-all-plots-together-in-ap

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We should attach the listener to the internal `Axes` object, and not the `UIAxes` itself. Try this:

```
hFig = uifigure();
hAx = uiaxes(hFig);
addlistener(struct(hAx).Axes, 'YLim', 'PostSet', @(src, evnt)disp("YLim changed"));
hAx.YLim = [0 2];
```

In case anybody is wondering, I found this via trial and error.

Tested on R2018a & R2018b.

Comment: rhooo ... very nice. I tried to dig but was kicked out of all these protected properties. The trick of using `struct` to bypass MATLAB protections ... Genius!

Comment: Let's just say that I started with a way more complicated approach (trying to interact with the WebGL renderer that draws the axes on the HTML canvas) before implementing the KISS principle which you see here :)

Comment: Wow. Nice hack! The warning message says it all: `Warning: Calling STRUCT on an object prevents the object from hiding its implementation details and should thus be avoided.` You just gave me superpowers! :)

Comment: @codeaviator just the sort of voices it's best to ignore (`warning('off','MATLAB:structOnObject');`) :)

Comment: Your nickname is Dev-iL but you are a God

Comment: Hehe @Carlos thanks for the compliment :) To be considered an above-average hacker would be enough for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for this solution! I was having a real problem with zooming in on 3D data on a UIAxes. The 3D axes contained a .png background raster map at z=0 ([plotted as a surface](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/426060-plot-2d-images-in-3d-scatter-plot)) and the 3D position of a UAV flight in x-y-x. When I would zoom in, the z would zoom as well and the new z limits would exclude the map I wanted always displayed. What was odd, is that setting

```
app.UIAxes2.Interactions = [zoomInteraction('Dimensions','xy')];
```

would correct the problem when zooming with the scroll wheel on my mouse, but if I selected the zoom toolbar button (clicking to zoom), it would still zoom in z. Really frustrating.

To get around this, I used your example, but added the listener to the 'ZLim' and made a callback function that would look at all the elements of the plot, and reset ZLim to include all the data whenever the ZLim changed.

```
warning('off','MATLAB:structOnObject');
addlistener(struct(app.UIAxes2).Axes, 'ZLim', 'PostSet', @(src,evnt)mapholdaltlims(app,app.UIAxes2));


    function [inclusivezlim] = mapholdaltlims(app,ax)
        objwithz = findobj(app.UIAxes2.Children,'-property','ZData');
        currmin_z = 0;
        currmax_z = 0;
        for i = 1:length(objwithz)
            currmin_z = min([min(min(objwithz(i).ZData)), currmin_z]);%Need double mins because data could be 2d surface
            currmax_z = max([max(max(objwithz(i).ZData)), currmax_z]);
        end
        inclusivezlim = [currmin_z currmax_z];
        ax.ZLim = inclusivezlim;
        %disp('Updated the limits')
    end
```

Man, what a pain this was. I am glad it now works. Thanks again.

Comment: This should be a comment to the answer, not an answer itself.